# Datastore solution for tag search

Tags: mongodb, search, solr, nosql

I've got millions of items ordered by a precomputed score.  Each item has many boolean attributes.
  Let says that there is about ten thousand possible attributes totally, each item having dozen of them.

I'd like to be able to request **in realtime** (few milliseconds) the top n items given ~any combination of attributes.

What solution would you recommend?  I am looking for something extremely scalable.

--
- We are currently looking at *mongodb* and array index, do you see any limitation ?
- *SolR*  is a possible solution but we do not need text search capabilities.

Comment: when you say "ordered by score" do you mean this is already precomputed? If so then SOLR may not provide any benefit. If not, then SOLR provides very powerful and customizable relevancy ranking.

Comment: Millions of items is not a problem for SOLR but 10,000 possible attributes _could_ be a problem. SOLR supports dynamic fields so you do not have to define all the attributes but memory could blow out with a wide/sparse schema? Others may be able to advise on this better.

Comment: @nickdos yes the score is precomputed. And I think you're right the tricky part is the big number of attributes. I don't know how mongodb handle this. Does it create one index per attributes ? Is it even possible to have that much indexes ? We are going to test anyway but I'd like to be sure we do not miss the correct strategy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongodb can handle what you want, if you stored your objects like this

```
{ score:2131, attributes: ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"], ... }
```

Then the following query will match all the items that have att1 and attr2

```
c = db.mycol.find({ attributes: { $all: [ "attr1", "attr2" ] } })
```

but this won't match it

```
c = db.mycol.find({ attributes: { $all: [ "attr1", "attr4" ] } })
```

the query returns a cursor, if you want this cursor to be sorted, then just add the sort parameters to the query like so

```
c = db.mycol.find({ attributes: { $all: [ "attr1", "attr2" ] }}).sort({score:1})
```

Have a look at [Advanced Queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries) to see what's possible.

Appropriate indexes can be setup as follows

```
db.mycol.ensureIndex({attributes:1, score:1})
```

And you can get performance information using

```
db.mycol.find({ attributes: { $all: [ "attr1" ] }}).explain()
```

Mongo explains how many objects were scanned, how long the operation took
and various other statistics.

Comment: Indeed mongodb seems to fit the need very well, but I worry about the efficiency. You did not mention indexes here. Is an index on attributes and scores enough in my case ...

Comment: I've added information about indexes. Make sure all your indexes fit into memory, otherwise your queries will get slow.

Comment: I read somewhere that there could be maximum 64 indexes on a collection. What happens in case of indexed array? Does it mean that mongo will create 10 000 indexes ?

Comment: The index created in this answer is a single index with multiple keys. The 'score' was the last key, because only the last key can be used for sorting. When an array is indexed, each element of the array is added to the index. What this means is that when you perform the query mentioned above, multiple nodes will have to be scanned to verify that they match the query.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, one index but the same document is indexed multiple time, one time for each value in the multikey.

Comment: I will accept your answer but actually we end up not using MongoDb because of serious write performance issues at large scale. Especially implying slave unavailability during replication, though we have large mongo cluster handled by very competent people. I will probably update the answer if we finally find a way to go. We are currently looking for a home-brewed solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what Mongo can deal with. The fact that your attributes are boolean type helps here. A possible schema is listed below:

```
[
    {
        true_tags:[attr1, attr2, attr3, ...],
        false_tags: [attr4, attr5, attr6, ...]
    },
]
```

Then we can index on **true_tags** and **false_tags**. And it should be efficient to search with $in, $all, ... query operators.

Comment: Sorry it was not very clear but by boolean I meant either the item has the attribute either not. Your answer still stand, but I am looking for more precise information. Is there limitation on that kind of index (seems that there is on key size, max number of index etc.. but maybe my info are old)? how does it works with sharding ?

Answer (score 2):

Redis would be a perfect candidate for

- *"the top n items" for "millions of items ordered by score"*

Redis has a built in data structure that you can start from: `Sorted Set` => every member of a Sorted Set is associated with score. Which for example can be ranked by score with [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore):

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE key min max [WITHSCORES] [LIMIT offset count]
```

I encourage you to look at Sorted Set [commands](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) and get a feel for Redis, as your problem (as it is stated) asks for it. You may of course keep as many attributes as you'd like within a single Set element.

---

As far as MongoDB, since you mentioned millions, unless you can bent incremental queries to work for your problem, I would *not* expect a sub second response.

As @nickdos mentioned Solr Relevancy is a quite powerful feature, but the number of attributes *will* be a problem, since it would need to keep all this attributes in memory for each item. Although a dozen for each may not be that bad => just try and see.