# Search by date & tags in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb

What are the different options for search by date & tags using java & mongodb?

What are the steps that should I keep in mind for storing dates & tags into mongo using java?

Comment: you want to know how to store data into the mongodb using java code ?

Comment: Yes I want to know about "How to store the date into mongodb using java?"

Comment: If I want to have query which will give records using search by date till "now". What should I use in java/mongodb for "now"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be nothing special about searching for dates over any other type of data. You can use comparators so you can search across date ranges for example. Any tags that you want to query on will obviously benefit from indexing so you might want to setup a multiple single indexes on these fields.

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Another question here about storing tag data and querying on it which goes into more detail.

[Datastore solution for tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391083/datastore-solution-for-tag-search)

Answer (score 1):

Here is following code for select a value from the mongodb with java. Hope it will help you.

```
MongoClient mongo=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("yourdb");
DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("yourtable");
BasicDBObject doc1=new BasicDBObject("email",email).
           append("password", password); 
DBCursor cours=coll.find(doc1);
if(cours.hasNext())
   {
       Map userdata=cours.next().toMap();
       String username=userdata.get("username").toString();  
       String email1=userdata.get("email").toString(); 
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes this code is for getting the results based on the query. But also I need something on date that is inserted & retrieved based on options.

Comment: date till now means present day date or some thing else

Comment: Date till now means the present day